# Custom Made Web Service returning NIL in iOS Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, web-services, rest, swift2

I am trying to learn how to make a web service on my apache server, and then service the resulting JSON to an iOS application.

My web service certainly returns JSON information when I input the url, which is MYIP/?code=1 (the code could be anything, this is only for testing). Here is my PHP web service:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Clayton
 * Date: 2/12/2016
 * Time: 6:18 PM
 */


    //process client request
    header("Content-Type:application/json");
    if(!empty($_GET['code'])){

        $code = $_GET['code'];

        $xml = simplexml_load_file("C:\Users\Clayton\Desktop\DataFiles\warehouse.city") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

        $sum1 = $xml->to;

        deliver_request(200,"Sum delivered", $sum1);
    }
    else{
         // throw invalid request
        deliver_request(404,"Sum not delivered", NULL);
    }

    function deliver_request($status, $status_message, $data){

        header("HTTP/1.1 $status, $status_message");

        $response['status'] = $status;
        $response['status_message'] = $status_message;
        $response['data'] = $data;

        $json_response=json_encode($response);
        echo $json_response;

    }





?>
```

Now the issue that I am having, is when I go onto the iOS end, the data response is returning NIL, and I'm not sure why. Here is the swift code

```
let url = NSURL(string: "35.11.183.52/?code=1")

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler:

            {(data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in



                // Read the Json

                do {

                    if let textString = NSString(data:data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){

                        //Parse the Json to get the text

                        let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(

                            data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                        let origin = jsonDictionary["status"] as! String



                        //update the label text

                        self.performSelectorOnMainThread("updateIPLabel:",

                            withObject: origin, waitUntilDone: false)

                   }

               } catch {

                    print("something went wrong")

                }

        }).resume()
```

Any advice on why I'm getting NIL returned would be greatly appreciated. Again, I can see a response when I manually enter the URL into a browser on iOS, but can pull anything from the app code for some reason.

Comment: are you getting anything for error?

Comment: Well what happens is when I create the JSON dictionary, and unwrap the data, I get a "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"

Comment: Before attempting to seralize, check the 'error'. If error is nil, then and only then can you look at what's in 'data'. If 'error' is not nil, then the data is not going to be valid, and you need to figure out why the HTTP request failed.

Next, for troubleshooting, I would print out the contents of 'textString', or debug and breakpoint and inspect it, to make sure you got what you thought you were getting.

Comment: Thanks! I am indeed getting an error in 'error.' Its a NSURLErrorDomain - code: 18446744073709550614. Have not had a much luck in a few Google searches with that. I will continue researching the error, but do you immediately know what exactly this would mean?

Comment: Don't know what that error code is, sorry. Try using the debug console to print out the 'error' and 'response':

     "po error" and "po response"

The response code might tell you something as well. 400 range can mean a lot of things but 500 tells you you got through to the server.